# When does Falcon 9 second stage separate?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, stages

For a regular LEO payload, when does the second stage separate?

Usually the first stage separate 2:30 min after launch (and it takes 6 minutes to come back to Earth) so how about the second one?

Aditionally it would be interesting to know how much time it spends between separation and burn in the atmosphere

Comment: You might try doing your own research for some of these questions. Googling for "<mission name> launch timeline" will be fruitful for this kind of question -- that's what I do to come up with the answers.

Comment: Thanks. On CRS missions it separates at about 10 minutes after lift off. On Anasis 2 (GEO) it separated at 32:29 min. https://spaceflightnow.com/2020/07/20/falcon-9-launch-timeline-with-anasis-2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the mission.  Starlink payloads seperate in low earth orbit pretty early.

GEO missions the second stage has to do multiple burns depending on the orbits.

CRS missions seperate pretty early as well since they stay in LEO to get to the ISS.

Comment: By multiple burns you mean the engines stop take a break and then start again?